# scan string for occurrences of a character in c

Tags: c, string

I found several answers to this in C++ or C#, but none for C.

I need to know how to count the number of characters in a string.  The goal is to determine whether there is a closed block (bounded by braces `'{'`, `'}'`) in a string.  right now I have the following:

```
int closedBlock(char* value) {
    int open = 0;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(value); i++) {
        if (!strcmp("{", value[i])) {
            open++;
        } else if (!strcmp("}", value[i])) {
            open--;
        }
    }

    return !open;
}
```

but it crashes after on the first `if` check.  I'm not really clear on why this does not work.  I imagine it has something to do with bad pointers (that seems to always be the problem in C), but I can't figure it out.  In addition to working code, and explanation of why mine is bad would be greatly helpful.

Thanks.

**NOTE**

I am aware that this simply check that the number of `'{'` is equal to the number of `'}'`, and not truly that there is a properly closed block.  I'll solve that problem after I solve this one.

Comment: `if (value[i] == '{')` value[i] is char, "{" is array of `{\0` and value[i] is evaluated for its ascii value so strcmp tries to walk 2 arrays "{" and one at pointer address 57 for example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) will compare two null-terminated strings. It still baffles me that your compiler actually doesn't mutter about the second parameter being a `char`. If you want to compare a single character just use the equal-operator `==`:

```
int closedBlock(char* value) {
    int open = 0;
    int length = strlen(value);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (value[i] == '{') {
            open++;
        } else if (value[i] == '}') {
            open--;
        }
    }

    return !open;
}
```

Hint: If you work with `gcc` add `-Wall -Wextra` to your compiler call, it will often result in useful warnings.

> I am aware that this simply check that the number of '{' is equal to the number of '}', and not truly that there is a properly closed block. I'll solve that problem after I solve this one.

Another hint here: when can there be an invalid block? If and only if the end-token `}` occurs without a preceding start-token `{`. You already have all tools for this, you're just missing another `if`-statement.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're trying to compare a string: `"{"` against a single character: `value[i]`.

`value` (presumably) points to an array of characters, while `value[i]` specifies a single one of those.  So you want to compare character-to-character like so:

```
for (i = 0; i < strlen(value); i++) {
    if (value[i] == '{') {
        open++;
    } else if (value[i] == '}') {
        open--;
    }
}
```

Note the use of **single** quotes around the `{` and `}`. That tells the compiler it's a single character and not a C-string.

Answer (score 0):

why you use `strcmp()` if you only compare one char?

you can simply use the `==` operator see my example:

http://ideone.com/dNCH2

best regards kenny